# Facebook Application get user information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

i am trying to write a Facebook application where once installed on a page provides a simple Form once this form is populated it would create a new table with this users username or userid.

So far i have the FBML form up and running using an external php file to process it all how can i get users username or userid to my forms php action file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the PHP SDK or the javascript SDK?  If you're using the PHP SDK, it's as simple as this:

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser(); // This is the FB user ID
$username;
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $username = $user_profile['username']; // this is the facebook username.
        // If the user hasn't set it manually, it will be something
        // like "john.doe.50"
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont ave the appId, secret yet seems i cant create an application yet i opened my FB account today you need to verify it with credit card an phone i did that but now it wants my photo id as well. Meh need to resolve that first.

Comment: Oh, really?  I created mine only a couple of weeks ago and it didn't ask for any of that.  Very strange!